# Can ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Property be set using XML config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

Can the property [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol) be defined statically in the xml config file rather than in code? 
I know from [servicePointManager Element (Network Settings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/servicepointmanager-element-network-settings) the property "SecurityProtocol" is not available. If anyone knows a way to override that it will be of great help. Thanks.